# TypeScript: Property 'isComposing' does not exist on type 'KeyboardEvent'

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ts-loader

I am creating a website page.
The script is written in TypeScript.
However, I get the following error when compiling to JavaScript.\

```
Property 'isComposing' does not exist on type 'KeyboardEvent'.
```

I would like to fix this as it is interfering with the execution of the script in the test environment, although it does work fine after compilation itself.\

I've encountered similar errors before and was able to resolve them by explicitly specifying the version in the lib of tsconfig.json. This time, however, I can't solve the problem because I don't know which ES version contains the property "isComposing".\

Please let me know if you know how to solve this problem. Thanks.
In addition, please excuse my poor English.\

The following is the typeScript code where the error occurs.

```
                input.addEventListener('keydown', function(e: KeyboardEvent) {
                    if(<boolean>e.isComposing == false) {
                        const key = e.key
                        const nowRowNum = tr.rowIndex;
                        if(['ArrowLeft','ArrowRight','Tab','ArrowDown','ArrowUp','Enter','Shift'].includes(key)) {
                            pressedKey[key] = true;
                        }
                        console.log(pressedKey);
                        
                        if((!pressedKey['Shift'] && ['ArrowLeft'].includes(key)) || (pressedKey['Shift'] && pressedKey['Tab'])) {//左セルへ移動
                            //input.blur();
                            const preCellIndex :number = td.cellIndex > 1 ? td.cellIndex-1 : td.cellIndex;;
                            table.rows[nowRowNum].cells[preCellIndex].click();
                        } else if(['ArrowUp'].includes(key) || (pressedKey['Shift'] && pressedKey['Enter'])) {//上セルへ移動
                            //input.blur();
                            const preRowNum :number = tr.rowIndex > 1 ? tr.rowIndex-1 : nowRowNum;
                            table.rows[preRowNum].cells[td.cellIndex].click();
                        
                        } else if(['Tab', 'ArrowRight'].includes(key) && !pressedKey['Shift']) {//右セルへ移動
                            //input.blur();
                            const nextCellIndex :number = td.cellIndex < table.rows[0].cells.length-2 ? td.cellIndex+1 : td.cellIndex;
                            table.rows[nowRowNum].cells[nextCellIndex].click();
                        } else if(['Enter', 'ArrowDown'].includes(key)) {//Enter時の挙動、下セルへ移動
                            input.blur();
                            const nextRowNum :number = nowRowNum < self.row_size ? nowRowNum+1 : nowRowNum;
                            table.rows[nextRowNum].cells[td.cellIndex].click();
                        }
                    }
                    
                });
```

And here's the contents of the tsconfig.json we're using.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib":["dom", "es2017","dom.iterable", "scripthost"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowJs":true,
    "outDir": "lib"
  },
  "exclude": [
      "dist",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Are you using react or its just typescript?

Comment: Your code work's fine https://tsplay.dev/WzAeQm even with a target of `ES3`. The problem is somewhere in code you have note posted.

Comment: And please confirm if you are getting the error at compile tie, or at the time of execution in the browser?

Comment: @ImanpalSingh It is just typescript. Not use React.

Comment: @JurijsKovzels That error occurs in both cases.